# A django app frontend error in IE and Chrome caused by iframe and ajax

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, internet-explorer

I have a app powered by django，

Page I:

http://dev.stackpop.org:8081/test/3/

Page II：

http://stackpop.org/helpme.html

Page II just include Page I with iframe

The above 2 page both work well in IE and chrome.

I use another domain name point to the app and visit page 2 which ref it as page 3：

http://www.jiongceyan.com/helpme.html

Actually, page 2 and page 3 is the same html file.However, page 2 works well in both IE and chrome, page 3 just work in chrome and can't work in IE.

when I open helpme.html as a local file in IE and chrome, it still can't work in IE.

---

THe 'doesn't work ' means if your click the button, the ajax doesn't work.

Comment: "page 3 just work in chrome and can't work in Chrome" - I presume one of those two Chromes was meant to be IE? (It all works in Firefox.) It might also help if you specify which version of IE you're using.

Comment: My IE is 8.0.  Is this a cross-domain problem? ~thx

Comment: If it's IE8, I don't believe it shouldn't be a cross domain problem - or at least not the type I'm familiar with. The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing stuff came in in IE9 (and Firefox, and it's working in Firefox anyway).